# Vue3に二次元配列を渡す方法

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, vue.js

Google Apps ScriptでVue3でテストアプリを作成しています。

クライアント側Javascriptでいろいろ試していますが、二次元配列がObject型？になるのか、v-forで回せません。どのように渡すと良いのでしょうか？
ベタ打ちの配列を返すと動作するので、CDN等の設定は問題ないとしてアドバイスをいただければと思います。

javascript.html

```
<script>
function initializeVue(values){

const app = {
  data(){
    return {
      lists: values
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(app).mount(‘#app’)

}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(initializeVue).getSpreadsheetValues();

</script>
```

code.gs

```
function getSpreadsheetValues()
{
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`クライアント側Javascriptでいろいろ試していますが、二次元配列がObject型？になるのか、v-forで回せません。`、`ベタ打ちの配列を返すと動作する`のような状況から、`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues()`の値にDate objectが含まれている可能性を考えました。この場合、`withSuccessHandler`で返された`values`は`null`になってしまいます。これは今のところ仕様のようです。[Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values)

そこで、次のような変更はいかがでしょうか。この変更では、`getSpreadsheetValues()`を下記のように変更してください。[`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)はセルの値をそのまま文字列として返します。

##### From:

```
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getValues();
```

##### To:

```
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
```

#### Note:

- もしも、スプレッドシートから取得した値のDate objectをJavascript側でもDate objectとして使用したい場合は、Google Apps Script側で一度文字列あるいはUnix timeに変更した後、Javascript側でDate objectに戻す操作が必要になるかと思われます。

Comment: スピーディーなご回答ありがとうございました。まさにTanaike様の仰るとおりDate型が入っておりました。Webで見つけたサンプルコードはたまたまDate型が含まれていなく、うまく動作していたようでした。

Comment: @masa ご返事ありがとうございます。Date objectが含まれると自動で戻り値全体がnullになる問題はStackoverflowでも問題になっていました。この場合、何らかのエラーメッセージを返すようにしているとユーザ側でその問題を理解しやすいのですが、今のところ、これについては変更なしのようです。